# For a NetworkStream, when to use WriteAsync and when to use BeginWrite?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, networking

In C#, for networking, when writing, it seems like there are two ways to write asynchronously to a socket using an instance of `NetworkStream`:

a) Await a `WriteAsync`

b) Use a `BeginWrite` and an `EndWrite`

For the life of me, I cannot understand when I should use one or the other, they seem identical.

Comment: Those are two paradigms for async programming. b) being the more legacy one. For new code, I'd always go for the async/Task API. See also : [Asynchronous programming patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/) The patterns mentioned in the article correspond to your a) as "Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)" and your b) would be "Asynchronous Programming Model (APM)"

Comment: They are (effectively) identical... consider the non-Task versions as effectively obsolete. The `XXXXAsync` versions, being task-based, are considerably easier to work with.

Comment: It is even mentioned in the documentation for BeginWrite - "Consider using WriteAsync(Byte[], Int32, Int32) instead"